# How can I print data in multiple table format from C# WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

Please have a look at the attached image. I have the data (BatchName) in my hand, but facing problem to print this data in attached format. I have no idea about where to start or what to look.

I am using VS2010 C#, Winform App, and wanted to print it from my application. Also, I am not allowed to use Crystal Report due to licencing issue and I haven't found any other reporting option in VS2010 either.

I want to print 8 set of data in a single A4 size paper like as below (image created in excel; the extra spacing between datasets can be omitted if needed).

Please help !

**Edit**

OK. Let me explain the scenario. I retrieved a list of batches and displaying them in a ListView control. Each batches in this listview contains its own details data and with each listViewItem, the corresponding batch (or you can say MasterData) was tagged. So that, when I select an item, I get the MasterData & the DetailData both. Now, what I am trying to do is, whenever I select 1 or more batches from this listview and click on a Button, each batches data will be printed in something similar to the attached image. But all the batches MUST be in separate blocks and in a 2 column format to reduce the paper requirement.

**Note:** Don't bother about the data retrieval part, only consider the data formatting & printing for A4 size papers.

[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you don't understand.  You only need the PrintDocument and Graphic classes to make this kind of printout.  Or just use Excel to make the printout for you, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ! I have done this by using the WebBrowser control in the winform. I generated the HTML tags according to my needs in the code behind the then set the browser control to render the text. Even though the outlook is not much impressive, but it would work for me.  Below is the code

```
private void GenerateHtmlText(List<TorTeeFileBO> torTeeFileBos)
{
    StringBuilder pageText = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder htmlText = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder styleText = new StringBuilder();

    List<TorTeeFileBO> allTorteeFilesEven = new List<TorTeeFileBO>();
    List<TorTeeFileBO> singleTorteeFile = new List<TorTeeFileBO>();

    int maxItem = 0;
    bool isDataFound = false;

    if (torTeeFileBos.Count % 2 == 0)
    {
        allTorteeFilesEven = torTeeFileBos;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < torTeeFileBos.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == torTeeFileBos.Count - 1)
            {
                singleTorteeFile.Add(torTeeFileBos[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                allTorteeFilesEven.Add(torTeeFileBos[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    pageText.Append("<html><head><title>QC Print</title></head><body>");

    if (torTeeFileBos.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allTorteeFilesEven.Count; i += 2)
        {
            maxItem = 0;
            isDataFound = false;

            htmlText.Append("<table>");
            htmlText.Append("<tr>");
            // 1st Row, 1st Column for Batch Name
            htmlText.Append("<td>");
            htmlText.Append("<b>");
            htmlText.Append("QC: ");
            htmlText.Append(cmbUsers.Text);
            htmlText.Append("</b>");
            htmlText.Append("</td>");
            htmlText.Append("<td>");
            htmlText.Append("<b>");
            htmlText.Append(" ; Batch No. : ");
            htmlText.Append(allTorteeFilesEven[i].FriendlyFileName);
            htmlText.Append("</b>");
            htmlText.Append("</td>");
            htmlText.Append("<td width='50px'></td>");
            // 1st Row, 2nd Column for Batch Name
            htmlText.Append("<td>");
            htmlText.Append("<b>");
            htmlText.Append("QC: ");
            htmlText.Append(cmbUsers.Text);
            htmlText.Append("</b>");
            htmlText.Append("</td>");
            htmlText.Append("<td>");
            htmlText.Append("<b>");
            htmlText.Append(" ; Batch No. : ");
            htmlText.Append(allTorteeFilesEven[i+1].FriendlyFileName);
            htmlText.Append("</b>");
            htmlText.Append("</td>");
            htmlText.Append("</tr>");

            StringBuilder tableHtml = new StringBuilder();

            if (allTorteeFilesEven[i].FileData.Count > allTorteeFilesEven[i+1].FileData.Count)
            {
                maxItem = allTorteeFilesEven[i].FileData.Count;
            }
            else if ((allTorteeFilesEven[i].FileData.Count < allTorteeFilesEven[i + 1].FileData.Count) || 
                (allTorteeFilesEven[i].FileData.Count == allTorteeFilesEven[i + 1].FileData.Count))
            {
                maxItem = allTorteeFilesEven[i+1].FileData.Count;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < maxItem; j++)
            {
                tableHtml.Append("<tr>");
                //1st Column Data
                tableHtml.Append("<td>");
                isDataFound = false;
                try
                {
                    tableHtml.Append(allTorteeFilesEven[i].FileData[j].Rec_Num);
                    isDataFound = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    tableHtml.Append("");
                    isDataFound = false;
                }
                tableHtml.Append("</td>");
                if(isDataFound)
                {
                    tableHtml.Append("<td>________________</td>");    
                }
                else
                {
                    tableHtml.Append("<td></td>"); 
                }
                //Column Separator
                tableHtml.Append("<td width='50px'></td>");
                //2nd Column Data
                tableHtml.Append("<td>");
                isDataFound = false;
                try
                {
                    tableHtml.Append(allTorteeFilesEven[i+1].FileData[j].Rec_Num);
                    isDataFound = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    tableHtml.Append("");
                    isDataFound = false;
                }
                tableHtml.Append("</td>");
                if (isDataFound)
                {
                    tableHtml.Append("<td>________________</td>");
                }
                else
                {
                    tableHtml.Append("<td></td>");
                }

                tableHtml.Append("</tr>");
            }
            htmlText.Append(tableHtml);
            htmlText.Append("<tr></tr>");
            htmlText.Append("</table>");
        }

        if (singleTorteeFile.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder singleHtml = new StringBuilder();

            singleHtml.Append("<table>");
            singleHtml.Append("<tr>");
            // 1st Row, 1st Column for Batch Name
            singleHtml.Append("<td>");
            singleHtml.Append("<b>");
            singleHtml.Append("QC: ");
            singleHtml.Append(cmbUsers.Text);
            singleHtml.Append("</b>");
            singleHtml.Append("</td>");
            singleHtml.Append("<td>");
            singleHtml.Append("<b>");
            singleHtml.Append(" ; Batch No. : ");
            singleHtml.Append(singleTorteeFile[0].FriendlyFileName);
            singleHtml.Append("</b>");
            singleHtml.Append("</td>");
            singleHtml.Append("<td width='50px'></td>");
            // 1st Row, 2nd Column for Batch Name
            singleHtml.Append("<td>");
            singleHtml.Append("");
            singleHtml.Append("");
            singleHtml.Append("</td>");
            singleHtml.Append("<td>");
            singleHtml.Append("");
            singleHtml.Append("</td>");
            singleHtml.Append("</tr>");

            StringBuilder singleTableHtml = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < singleTorteeFile[0].FileData.Count; j++)
            {
                singleTableHtml.Append("<tr>");
                singleTableHtml.Append("<td>");
                singleTableHtml.Append(singleTorteeFile[0].FileData[j].Rec_Num);
                singleTableHtml.Append("</td>");
                singleTableHtml.Append("<td>________________</td>");
                singleTableHtml.Append("</tr>");
            }
            singleHtml.Append(singleTableHtml);
            singleHtml.Append("</table>");

            htmlText.Append(singleHtml);
        }
    }

    pageText.Append(styleText);
    pageText.Append(htmlText);
    pageText.Append("</body></html>");

    wbPagePreview.DocumentText = pageText.ToString();
}
```

Comment: what is wbPagePreview and how to use it?